# Knockout JS - How to un-track changes when Cancel button is clicked ?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following code. When a preset is selected, it will trigger the following.

- Assign selectedPreset
- Assign selectedField1
- Assign selectedCategories

  ```
  self.viewSelectedPreset = function (_selectedPreset) {
      self.editMode(true);

      self.selectedPreset(_selectedPreset);
      self.selectedField1(_selectedPreset.Field1);
      self.selectedCategories(_selectedPreset.CategoryC);

  };
  ```

And my cancel button has the following code, in which I have unassign

- selectedPreset
- selectedField1
- selectedCategories

  ```
  self.cancelUpdatePreset = function () {
      self.editMode(false);

      self.selectedPreset({});
      self.selectedField1([]);
      self.selectedCategories([]);

  };
  ```

[category is checked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ0ks.png)
The problem is when user selected Category 1, it seems selectedPreset.CategoryC is also updated and the changes is always tracked.

How can I fix this cancel button issue?
What am I missing?
Thanks in advance, everyone.

[jsFiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/0xf9hj24/)

Comment: You may find [this article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html) useful.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @f_martinez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by Martinez, I have fixed the cancel button issue.

```
// Cancel changes
self.cancelUpdatePreset = function () {
    self.editMode(false);

    self.selectedPreset(null);
    self.PresetInEditing(null);

    //console.info("cancelUpdatePreset", ko.toJS(self.PresetInEditing()));
};
```

Reference: [knockmeout](http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html)

Completed [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/fybtLu6x/)